# Python Syntax Error?

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax-error

I am tinkering around with a simple game in Python and it won't run because of this syntax error:

```
intro = 'Greetings! What\'s your name?'

Hunter = 'Oh, Hey Hunter! Hows life?'
Spencer = 'Go away you stupid piece of crap!!!'
David = 'Hey dad.'

def Questions():
    print intro
    answer = raw_input("Well?").upper()
    if answer == 'Spencer' or answer == 'spencer'
        print Spencer
    elif answer == 'Hunter' or answer == 'hunter'
        print Hunter
    elif answer == 'David' or answer == 'david'
        print David
        else:
            print 'Sorry! I don\'t know you!'
            Questions()

Questions()
```

It won't show on this sample but python won't run this because it says there is a Syntax error on line 10 (right after 'spencer') can somebody please explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Put a colon at the end of the `if` statement line, and the `elif`. Anywhere you will indent the next line, you need a colon.

Also, your `else` statement is not indented properly. It should line up with the `elif` above it.

And you can use `.lower()` to convert a string to lowercase so you only have to do one comparison. Ah... I didn't notice you're already using `.upper()`. Same thing either way, you only need one comparison.

With those changes, your `Question` function would look like this:

```
def Questions():
    print intro
    answer = raw_input("Well?").lower()
    if answer == 'spencer':
        print Spencer
    elif answer == 'hunter':
        print Hunter
    elif answer == 'david':
        print David
    else:
        print 'Sorry! I don\'t know you!'
        Questions()
```

Answer (score 1):

you should add `:` after your `if` statement.

```
if answer == 'Spencer' or answer == 'spencer':
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a `:` at the end of each of the if and elif statements.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the colon on the if.

```
if answer == 'Spencer' or answer == 'spencer':
```

Comment: When a compiler tells you there's an error on line 10, that means "somewhere around line 10 I got confused." The actual error is quite likely to be earlier in the file.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a colon missing at the end of the if condition